# Chapter page formatting

Tags: formatting, header-footer, chapters

I'm using MiKTeX and when I use `\chapter` command, it starts a new page. I was wondering how to not start a new page.

My next concern is how can I align the text `\chapter{*}` where `*` is the text.

Lastly, I found a code online that right aligns at the top of the page the page number, but every time I get to a new chapter page, the page number is at the bottom center. Is there a way to change the position of the page number because every time I add a new chapter in my document which is set to `report`, it is at the bottom center instead of top right.

Thanks.

EDIT: I was able to change the size of the text in `\chapter{*}` where `*` is the text.

Comment: Related reading: http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2521

Comment: `article` class does not contain a `\chapter` command.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @jay, oh yeah that's right. I changed my document type to report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `chapter` command is defined in [`report`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/report) as

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

You'll notice that line 1 has the part that we need to comment out, which does the page breaking. Also note that when using `\documentclass{article}` you don't have access to the `\chapter` command.

So, in the MWE below, I've redefined `\chapter` and simply commented out the part with `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{%\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{lions}

\chapter{zebras}
\end{document}
```

For your question about headers and footers, I recommend the [`fancyhdr`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) package.

In relation to your alignment of the chapter title, we'd need to see some more details. Almost certainly though, the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package would be able to do the heavy lifting for us.

Just as a cautionary note, removing the `clearpage` and `cleardoublepage` command could cause some undesired consequences, especially concerning floats (`figure`, `table`, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't think I would have come up with this. I couldn't find anything online to the best of my abilities on how to stop the page break when using \chapter{*}.

Comment: @user178500 you're very welcome :) Happy TeXing :)